# Attributes and let statements in type members

Tags: f#

I am using FsUnit to write some unit tests in F# and I have noticed some odd behaviour around attributes and let statements in type members and was wondering if anyone could explain it?

If I write a test like this:

```
[<Fact>] member test.
  ``Test that something works correctly`` () =

    let x = 1

    x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

I will get an error in Visual Studio 2012 on the first character of the 'x + 2' line saying:

> Unexpected keyword 'let' or 'use' in expression. Expected 'in' or other token.

Using 'let ... in' gets around this error, although if you want to use more than one let it gets messy quickly:

```
[<Fact>] member test.
  ``Test that something works correctly`` () =
    let x = 1
    in x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

I eventually discovered that having the attribute on a separate line also gets around the error:

```
[<Fact>]
member test.
  ``Test that something works correctly`` () =

    let x = 1

    x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

Can anyone provide any insight on why the first code snippet causes the error but the other two do not?

Comment: It looks like an indentation issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first snippet, you actually had two indentation errors. The first issue is that `''Test that something works correctly''` should be indented after `member` keyword. The second one is the body of the function should be indented after all lines of member definitions.

If you fix the first error:

```
[<Fact>] member test.
           ``Test that something works correctly`` () =
    let x = 1
    x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

the compiler will issue a "Possible incorrect indentation" warning, which you can fix by indenting the body of the function further:

```
[<Fact>] member test.
           ``Test that something works correctly`` () =
             let x = 1
             x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

In second snippet, the use of `in` keyword triggers [verbose syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233199.aspx) where indentation doesn't matter anymore. In the last example, `member` happens to have lowest indentation; you incidentally have correct indentation.

That said, you should avoid break member definitions into multiple lines. In most of the cases, you can just use `let` bindings instead of more verbose `member` bindings.

```
[<Fact>]
let ``Test that something works correctly``() =
    let x = 1
    x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

Comment: Or, `let [<Attribute>] name = ...`

Comment: @pad Interesting about the indentation in multi-line members; if I keep the name on the next line but indent it beyond the member keyword it works.

Comment: @RamonSnir I didn't know you could apply the attribute after the let, very handy.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments, you can put the attribute after `let` or after `member`. This way, you can put the annotation and the member definition on a single line:

```
let [<Fact>] ``Test that something works correctly``() =
   let x = 1
   x + 2 |> should equal 3
```

There is also a case when you actually *need* to use this syntax. If you have multiple mutually recursive functions (that may call each other), then you need to define them using `let rec ... and` and in that case, you have to put the attributes after `and`:

```
let rec [<Test>] a () = 10
and [<Test>] b () = 10
```

But the following would not be valid syntax:

```
[<Test>] 
let rec a () = 10
[<Test>] 
and b () = 10
```